# What's the proper escaping of the following string for find and replace?

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to use the following instructions

http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html

To replace all occurrences of

```
<BASE href="file://C:\Users\J\Documents\Personal\J\">
```

with nothing.  I have tried

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/<BASE href=\"file:\/\/C:\\Users\\J\\Documents\\Personal\\J\\">//g' {} \;
```

But it's not working likely because something is wrong with escaping characters.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: your code works here though

Comment: If you don't think there'll be close matches, you can replace tricky characters with `.`:  `sed 's/<BASE href=.file:..C:.Users.J.Documents.Personal.J.>//g'`.  This is unlikely to find any false matches, but that is a judgement call.  You know your data better than I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the substitution delimiter helps a lot:

```
 find . -type f -exec sed -i \
     's!<BASE href="file://C:\\Users\\J\\Documents\\Personal\\J\\">!!g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
s/\<BASE href\="file:\/\/C:\\Users\\J\\Documents\\Personal\\J\\\"\>//g
```

or try with perl with the same same command i.e., 
instead of `sed -i` use `perl -pi`